# Instructions for Pegs and Jokers by Fundex

Tags: pegs-and-jokers

Does anyone have the instructions and rules for the Pegs and Jokers Game made by Fundex? They used their own deck of cards instead of a poker deck.  I would also be interested in obtaining a complete game since the company no longer makes it.

Comment: emailed customerservice @ fundex, will see if they respond.

Comment: Since you specifically mention Fundex, I think this may not be what you're looking for, but rules for a game called Pegs and Jokers (with no mention of Fundex) can be found [here](http://www.pagat.com/misc/pegsandjokers.html). They also have links to some place that makes boards, but I don't see any mention of special cards.

Answer (score 3):

Shelly Christopher at Fundex sent me rules which are a copy of the rules found [here](http://www.aboardgamesdatabase.com/rules/pegsnjokers/index.htm)